# Multiple javascript functions in one file

Tags: javascript

I used some bootstrap javascript functions and one swiper function in one file. Problem is the swiper function doesnt work if i put it last in the code. If I put it first it works fine but the other functions stop working.  How to seperate them correctly so that each function is loaded fine.

```
/* SIDEBAR */           
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});


/* SIDEBAR COLLAPSE */  
$('.collapse').collapse()
$('.collapse-up').on('click',function(){
$('.collapse').collapse('hide');
});


/* ON/OFF BUTTON */ 
$("[name='checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch();

/* LOGIN MODAL*/  
$('#login').modal(options) ;


/* RATING SLIDER */
$('#rate').slider({
formatter: function(value) {
tooltip: 'always'
return   value + ' % ';
}
});


/* SWIPER */ 
    var swiper = new Swiper('.keyword-swiper', {
    slidesPerView: 2,
    scrollbarHide: true,
    grabCursor: true,
    paginationClickable: true,
    spaceBetween: 0,
    freeMode: true,
});
```

Comment: Get rid of this for a start: `<!--scrollbar: '.swiper-scrollbar',-->`. It's not JS syntax and will cause a error which will appear in your console (F12 in firefox).

Answer (score 1):

`<!--scrollbar: '.swiper-scrollbar',-->` is not valid JavaScript. You need to use the `/* */` comment style:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.keyword-swiper', {
/* scrollbar: '.swiper-scrollbar', */
slidesPerView: 2,

...
```

Or the `//` comment style:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.keyword-swiper', {
// scrollbar: '.swiper-scrollbar',
slidesPerView: 2,

...
```

The JavaScript interpreter tries to interpret `<!-- -->` (an HTML comment) as JS code.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning the `<!-- -- >` style is HTML comment style, otherwise a perfect answer.

Comment: sorry,,,that wasnt supposed to be there...i got u little confused..but as i said...the functions work fine...but only in different order ..if i put the swiper first it works ok but all the other functions fail...if i put swiper as the last function - it fails and all the other work fine.....i just pasted the codes they work fine in html...the moment i put them in one .js file they fail ((these functions are in different html pages which load the .js file before all the other neccessary libraries.)) but they just wont work if together